# Need commands to fetch Guest VM OS version from Xen and KVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, xen

I m looking for the commands that can be executed to fetch the OS Version of the VMs running on the below Hypervisors.

1. Xen (Not the citrix Xen server, but the Xen Sever hosted on a ubuntu Machine)
2. KVM